# Cannot send multiple select spinner values to php server in android

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

The code for sending data to the php server is given below

```
dataOutputStreamRegister.writeBytes("txtUserID="+userName+"&txtPassword="+userPassword+"&ddlCountry="+countryId
                    +"&ddlUniversity="+universityId+"&ddlCourseYear="+courseYearId+"&txtEmail="+userEmail+"&txtInitial="+userInitials
                    +"&txtFname="+userFirstName+"&txtLname="+userLastName+"&txtDob="+userBirthMonth+"/"+userBirthDay+"/"+userBirthYear
                    +"&ddlLevel="+levelId+"&txtSkills="+studentSkills+"&ddlGender="+genderId+"&ddlFraternity="+fraternityId+"&ddlSorority="
                    +sororityId+"&ddlClubs="+clubId);
dataOutputStreamRegister.flush();
dataOutputStreamRegister.close();
```

I cannot get the club id values

The clubid variable sent to the php server is `23,25` right now

The php code at the server is given below

```
foreach ($infoArray['ddlClubs'] as $key) {
   if(!checkValidCategory($key,'clubs'))
   {
       $errorMessage='Invalid club.';
       $validResult=false;
       break;
   } 

}
```

The format should be

```
 Array
(
[txtUserID] => abcd@vyrazu.com
[txtPassword] => 123456
[ddlCountry] => select country
[ddlUniversity] => select university
[ddlCourseYear] => select course year
[txtEmail] => 
[txtInitial] => 
[txtFname] => 
[txtLname] => 
[txtDob] => 
[ddlLevel] => select level
[txtSkills] => 
[ddlGender] => select gender
[ddlFraternity] => 
[ddlSorority] => 
[ddlClubs] => Array
    (
        [0] => 27
        [1] => 28
        [2] => 29
    )

)
```

Thanks everyone for your time

Comment: `The clubid variable sent to the php server is 23,25 right now`. You mean `String clubid = "22,23";`  ?

Comment: Show more php code. Especially where you define `$infoArray`.

Comment: `multiple select spinner values`. There aren't any in your code.